# Google Composer creation failed in service project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

While Google composer private environment creation in service project, I am trying to use subnet from host project. I have given editor role to composer service account as well as to composer APIs service agent account to fix permission issues. Still I am getting below error. Is it firewall issue? What firewall settings we need here?

Environment couldn't be created, but no error was surfaced.

```
This can be caused by a lack of proper permissions. Check if this environment's service account XXXXXX@YYYYYYY.iam.gserviceaccount.com has the 'roles/composer.worker' role and there is no firewall inhibiting internal communications set.
Http error status code: 400
Http error message: BAD REQUEST
Error messages:
    {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/compute-v1:compute.networks.listPeeringRoutes","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Required 'compute.networks.listPeeringRoutes' permission for 'projects/HOST_PROJECT/global/networks/dev-networks'","reason":"forbidden"}],"message":"Required 'compute.networks.listPeeringRoutes' permission for 'projects/HOST_PROJECT/global/networks/dev-networks'","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/HOST_PROJECT/global/networks/dev-networks/listPeeringRoutes","httpMethod":"GET","suggestion":"Consider granting permissions to ZZZZZZ@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"}}
```

Comment: Could you provide what exactly you want to achieve and all steps/commands you have done (without sensitive data). Did you use any tutorials? This is the full error message? I'd like to test this on my env.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was able to resolve it. It was permission issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this with below resolution:

Provided 'host network user' permissions in Host Project to Google APIs Service Agent account (serviceAccount:@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com) specific to host project network shared with service project (role = "roles/compute.networkUser")